# Git checkout effect on local workspace

Tags: git

I'm just starting to wrap my head around git but am confused about different commands affect my local workspace. From what I understand, your git directory is volatile in the sense that performing commands like `checkout` and `pull` will actually change the files in your git directory on your machine if it is necessary.

If I have a file open in an editor then perform one of these commands in terminal that changes my workspace, what happens exactly? For example, I have a file on one branch, then I checkout to master which doesn't have that file same file, and when I try save the file in the editor I get error: `The location of the document “blahFile” cannot be determined.`

Comment: The "exactly" part is a bit OS-dependent.  In general Git just writes to your work-tree using whatever the standard OS facilities are for creating, removing, and rewriting-existing files.  What your editor does with that is editor-dependent as well: most well-behaved Unix-ish editors today notice that a file was changed independently; and I believe Windows editors tend to place mandatory locks on files and not allow them to be changed (so that the underlying Git commands just fail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pull` fetches changes from the remote repository and tries to merge the changes into your current working directory. If it succeeds cleanly, it creates a new commit with the merge result. If not, it aborts the merge and you have to resolve the conflicts yourself (you use git add to mark a file as resolved). Therefore, it's preferred to have a clean working directory before pulling, or stash your work, or commit the work in a another branch.

`checkout`, if used with paths, it overwrites the file specified with the version you want (either from a previous commit or from index). If you use checkout to switch between branches or move from and to commits, if the working directory is clean, it changes the files in the working directory and the index to match exactly the commit you are going to. If the working directory isn't clean, it will try to do a trivial merge without affecting the modified files. If it fails, it won't proceed.

To build a better understanding, try reading [this tutorial](https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/15/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-1-intro/). I think it's pretty well written.